# Interfacing MAX7219 with Bus Pirate v3.6

Tags: spi, serial-bus

I am currently trying to interface a MAX7219 LED driver with a Bus Pirate 3.6 (Firmware v5.10 (r559)  Bootloader v4.4).

I have the following circuit breadboarded (along with some decoupling caps on the power rail):

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I have set up SPI mode as such:

```
Set speed:
 1. 30KHz
 2. 125KHz
 3. 250KHz
 4. 1MHz

(1)>4
Clock polarity:
 1. Idle low *default
 2. Idle high

(1)>1
Output clock edge:
 1. Idle to active
 2. Active to idle *default

(2)>1
Input sample phase:
 1. Middle *default
 2. End

(1)>1
CS:
 1. CS
 2. /CS *default

(2)>2
Select output type:
 1. Open drain (H=Hi-Z, L=GND)
 2. Normal (H=3.3V, L=GND)

(1)>2
Ready
```

Putting the MAX7219 into test mode and turning it off using `[0xFF,0xFF]` and `[0xFF, 0x00]` respectively turns all the LEDs on and off as expected. Restarting everything, I then run the following commands to disable character decoding (to use the MAX as a simple LED array drive), set maximum brightness, enable all columns, and finally enable the display:

```
[0x09,0x00]
[0x0A,0xFF]
[0x0B,0x07]
[0x0C,0x01]
```

Finally, sending the following eight commands to enable all LEDs akin to what test mode would do does not have any effect, and no LEDs light up;

```
[0x01, 0xFF]
[0x02, 0xFF]
[0x03, 0xFF]
[0x04, 0xFF]
[0x05, 0xFF]
[0x06, 0xFF]
[0x07, 0xFF]
[0x08, 0xFF]
```

At any point, I can set or reset test mode and it works as expect, so I'm convinced that SPI communication integrity is not the issue here.

I have tried this with both 5V and 3V3 levels for VCC, with the same results. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: Just comparing with code I have handy, the only difference is the intensity setting - try changing `[0x0A,0xFF]` to something lower like `[0x0A,0x03]`

Comment: Just tried it, no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, actually, as it turns out, SPI communication integrity was, in a way, the issue.

Contrary to anecdotal reports, the MAX7219 isn't as friendly to 3V3 logic as many people say it is. Using 5V for the power rails, putting 15K pullup resistors on the /CS, CLK, and MOSI lines, and setting the Bus Pirate to open drain mode resolved the issue.